# Register a User half way with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Due to the requirements of my app, I need the ability to create Users server-side using only their email addresses. This acts as a sort of invitation when a friend of theirs adds them to a group when they dont have an account yet. I'll be sending the invited user an email to notify them, containing a link where they can "create" their account. I'd like to know if Devise has any built in support for scenarios like this. If not, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member of #devise recommended the following gem:
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Seems to be exactly what I was looking for.